What does "That's a lollipop" mean?
In Sweet Smell of Success (1957), at the bar, press agent Sidney Falco approaches Frank D’Angelo, who is sitting and watching guitarist Steve Dallas perform with the band on stage:

Frank: Joe, give my nephew a drink.
Sidney: Your nephew doesn't want a drink.

Attention then shifts to guitarist Steve Dallas:

Frank: That's a lollipop, that boy. The kid's only great.

What does "That's a lollipop" mean?




A lollipop is just a nice and sweet candy, is that boy equally nice and sweet maybe?

@OldPadawan - There's a couple of possibilities. Lollipop is a slang term for 'a rounded guitar' and it's also a term for 'a young gay man'. I don't think either are relevant here, despite their obvious attraction as potentials matches.

Given the context and Frank's great big grin, it's clear is that he's happy about Dallas being very talented.
The kid isn't just good, he's great and "that's a lollipop", e.g.

Lollipop: Anything specially good, e.g. the pride of one’s collection
(American Slang - Ca. 1960s)
Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English 8th Ed.

Sidney points out that with 10% of the kid's future income as his theatrical agent, it's no wonder Frank is enjoying the sweet taste of success.

"Only" here is used in the sense of 'nothing less than' as opposed to 'merely'.

I agree, the way this is said (I added a video clip to the question) its clearly a compliment

Looking at the script, the follow-on line is a reply saying that Frank gets 10% so that makes Frank great. Frank has a PR contract with Dallas and derives income from him.
I am inclined to interpret this line to mean that Dallas is not good enough to be well-and-truly great and therefore he isn't a "meal ticket," just a snack.

I think you've misunderstood the line. The "kid's only great" is a compliment.
